Not capable of checking a falsy value at the validation middleware
I've found a weird behavior when trying to check for a falsy value. I guess it is related to the parser across the HTTP. All values inserted (eg http://www.localhost:3000/knex/0) are converted into strings: falsy values like 0 or '' are converted into "0" and "''" respectively. Therefore, when trying to check for falsy values doesn't raise an error.
May I be doing something wrong or is it something related to the library ?
My express-validator version: ^7.1.0
I left an example to test it:
const { body, validationResult, checkSchema, param } = require('express-validator');


const customChecker = (value) => {
  console.log('\ncustom');
  console.log((value));
  console.log(Boolean(value));
  //if (value === 0) {console.log(value)}
  if (value === '') {console.log(value)}
  if (!Boolean(value)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid id values. custom func');
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

const idSchema = {
  id: {
    //in: ['params'],
    notEmpty:{errorMessage: "Not id provided"},
    custom: { options: value => customChecker(value) },
    //exists: { options: { values: 'falsy' } }
  }
}


const validateId = [
 // param('id').notEmpty().withMessage('ID is required'),
 checkSchema(idSchema),

  (req, res, next) => {
    const VALRES = validationResult(req);
    if (!VALRES.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: VALRES.array() });
    }
    next();
  }
];


module.exports = { validateId };

app.get('/knex/:id',validateId, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const item = await knex('tablename').where({ id: req.params.id });
    res.json(item); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('ERROR:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }); 
  }
});


This is the standard behaviour of formData.
However JSON data works as you expect.
Please see below an MRE - minimal reproducible example.
The two requests pass a value of 0 into the two APIs in two different formats - FormData and JSON data respectively. While FormData converts it into a truthy value - “0”, JSON data retains it as a falsy value.
Please also see in detail the console output it generated.
One of the possible solutions to the problem is to make use of the option - checkFalsy: true. This has also been
show in the MRE.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const app = express();

app.post(
  '/formdata',
  multer().any(),
  body('somekey').exists({ checkFalsy: true }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(
      `formData : value ${req.body.somekey} typeof ${typeof req.body.somekey}, ${
        req.body.somekey ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'
      }`
    );
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
      console.log('no errors');
      return res.send('done');
    }
    console.log({ errors: result.array() });
    res.send('failed');
  }
);

app.post(
  '/jsondata',
  express.json(),
  body('somekey').exists({ checkFalsy: true }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(
      `JSON data : value ${req.body.somekey} typeof ${typeof req.body.somekey}, ${
        req.body.somekey ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'
      }`
    );
    const result = validationResult(req);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
      console.log('no errors');
      return res.send('done');
    }
    console.log({ errors: result.array() });
    res.send('failed');
  }
);

const data = new FormData();
data.set('somekey', 0);
fetch('http://localhost:3000/formdata', { method: 'POST', body: data });

fetch('http://localhost:3000/jsondata', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ somekey: 0 }),
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`l@3000`));

Test run
node server.js

Server console output
JSON data : value 0 typeof number, falsy
{
  errors: [
    {
      type: 'field',
      value: 0,
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      path: 'somekey',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ]
}
formData : value 0 typeof string, truthy
no errors

Citations:
FormData converts numeric input field to string

Thank you for the response. Complete MRE. Your answer is a little bit tricky since it uses POST and sets the body using JSON.stringify. What about a GET and params and query properties? As it says in one of the posts that you mentioned: "All values sent by HTML to the server-side are received as strings. You have to convert that data into integers in the backside". Then, I tried to set a built-in middleware like express.json([options]) type or extended options but it didn't work. The only way to manage it is by creating a custom middleware that manually converts the values.

In such a case, I guess this must be implemented by express-validator. Tell me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Hi, Thank you for your feedback and the vote. Shall revert as early as possible.

Hi, Sorry for the delay. I have added three more answers, posted separately. It tries to address the questions you have asked. Please see if it make sense.

Then, I tried to set a built-in middleware like express.json([options]) type or extended options but it didn't work. ?
That may not work. The body parsers will work only with respect to the content it has been configured for. It means, for example, express.json middleware will parse the incoming request only if its content type is “application/json”. The content type represented in the request should match the content type of the middleware which is “application/json” by default.
While sending a formdata,
the content type in the request will be either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or “multipart/form-data”. In such a case, the server should parse the incoming request with the respective middlewares. Otherwise it will fail to generate the expected body object. You may be able to see more content on this topic here:
Citation:
content-type should match
express built-in middlewares

The only way to manage it is by creating a custom middleware that manually converts the values. In such a case, I guess this must be implemented by express-validator. Tell me if I'm misunderstanding something.
This is something for us to discuss.
Let us see a simple html form as shown below. The only input in it is a number input. Though its type is number, the default value is number, min and max values are also set with numbers, the actual data is a text value which includes only numeric letters.
It is basically not a number type value since there is no way (or no need) in html to specify that. Therefore from the html point of view, it is a text value, and the respective parsers also treat this value as text at the server side. Therefore the parsers do not convert a number to text when it parse the data. The data at the source - in the html, itself is text.
However this is not the case with JSON data. In JSON format, we have the ways to handle a typed value. It means, the input element, we saw in the html can be represented in two different forms as below.
as a number type value:
{
somenumber : 1
}

as a text type value:
{
somenumber : “1”
}

However in a html form, we can have only one way - that is text always.
'  <input
'    type="number"
'    value="10"
'  />

Even if we code the html as below, value without quotes, on loading in Browser, it will again be with quotes.
'      <input
'        type="number"
'        value=10
'      />

So the point we are trying to reach here, the parsers do not convert, it is text at the html source itself.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const table = require('table');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('./'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
let output = [];

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  output.push([
    `form data : value ${req.body.somenumber}`,
    `typeof ${typeof req.body.somenumber}`,
    `${req.body.somenumber ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'}`,
  ]);

  console.log(table.table(output));
  return res.send('done');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`l@3000`));

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Sample HTML
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/post" method="post">
      <label>Enter a number between 10 and 100</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="somenumber"
        name="somenumber"
        min="10"
        max="100"
        value="10"
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

Test run results
l@3000
╔══════════════════════╤═══════════════╤════════╗
║ form data : value 10 │ typeof string │ truthy ║
╚══════════════════════╧═══════════════╧════════╝


What about a GET and params and query properties?
Please see another MRE below. It includes four different content. Please see in the table below that form-data, route parameters and query string values are all treated as text. Only JSON data retains the type.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const table = require('table');

const app = express();
let output = [];

app.get('/routeparam_qs/:somekey1', (req, res) => {
  output.push([
    `Route parameter : value ${req.params.somekey1}`,
    `typeof ${typeof req.params.somekey1}`,
    `${req.params.somekey1 ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'}`,
  ]);

  output.push([
    `Query string : value ${req.query.somekey2}`,
    `typeof ${typeof req.query.somekey2}`,
    `${req.query.somekey2 ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'}`,
  ]);
  return res.send('done');
});

app.post('/formdata', multer().any(), (req, res) => {
  output.push([
    `formData : value ${req.body.somekey}`,
    `typeof ${typeof req.body.somekey}`,
    `${req.body.somekey ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'}`,
  ]);
  return res.send('done');
});

app.post('/jsondata', express.json(), (req, res) => {
  output.push([
    `JSON data : value ${req.body.somekey}`,
    `typeof ${typeof req.body.somekey}`,
    `${req.body.somekey ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'}`,
  ]);
  console.log(table.table(output));
  return res.send('done');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`l@3000`);
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/routeparam_qs/0?somekey2=0', {
    method: 'GET',
  });

  const data = new FormData();
  data.set('somekey', 0);
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/formdata', { method: 'POST', body: data });

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/jsondata', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ somekey: 0 }),
  });
});

Test run results
l@3000
╔═══════════════════════════╤═══════════════╤════════╗
║ Route parameter : value 0 │ typeof string │ truthy ║
╟───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────╢
║ Query string : value 0    │ typeof string │ truthy ║
╟───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────╢
║ formData : value 0        │ typeof string │ truthy ║
╟───────────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────╢
║ JSON data : value 0       │ typeof number │ falsy  ║
╚═══════════════════════════╧═══════════════╧════════╝

